# Run a C# windwos application from a flutter app

Tags: c#, flutter, windows, flutter-qrcode

I'm building a Flutter app with a QR code scanner feature. I've successfully implemented it on both Android and iOS using the Flutter package [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) without any issues.

However, when it came to the Windows platform, I couldn't find any package that supports it. So, I ended up creating a C# Windows Forms application to handle the QR code scanning, and it's working fine.

Now, I'm looking for a way to bridge the gap between this Windows Forms application and my Flutter app. I want to be able to call the Windows Forms application from my Flutter app and receive the scanned QR code result back inside my Flutter app.

I've tried following some tutorials that involve using a file.dll, but I haven't had any success with that approach.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.